# Website not loading jQuery with bundles

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have an application in MVC5, using c#, HTML and jQuery.

In my localhost everything works fine and I have no major errors. However, when I publish the project (right-click project -> publish) and send the results to the Public Server, I have loading errors everywhere:

[image]

I have checked the resulting ZIP file and I am 100% that all tje jQuery files are in there, so the files are not missing.

At this point I think there may be a loading problem or something, but I have no idea what it could be. What is causing my server to not be able to load jQuery ?

My Bundle.cs file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-editable.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-editable.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-switch.js",
                    "~/Scripts/select2.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrapSwitch.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Amaris.XEditable.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js",
                    "~/Scripts/AmarisFeedback.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
            "~/Scripts/custom.js",
            "~/Scripts/fakeauth.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.dynatree.js",
            "~/Scripts/TableFilter.js",
            "~/Scripts/PackageScripts.js",
            "~/Scripts/MaterialScripts.js",
            "~/Scripts/PendingTableScripts.js",
            "~/Scripts/NotificationScripts.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        //notfitications for all the family! http://www.jqueryrain.com/?sPi0WIEh
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/notifIt").Include("~/Scripts/notifIt.js"));
```

And this is where I load the bundles:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>

<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/notifIt")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: JS is being loaded, that is why you're getting the missing reference errors in the other JS files - it's only jquery.js that's missing. Is jquery included *first* in the page?

Comment: Check your scripts import order.

Comment: Use `@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.js")"` for the source.

Comment: What do you render in the `head` section for the page? If you try and use jquery there its not loaded yet

Comment: So I should load all my scripts at the top of the page, instead of doing it in the end of the body?

Comment: Jquery should be the first to be included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the problem was VisualStudio itself. 
After analyzing the ZIP file created by VS when Publishing the project (right click -> Publish) we noticed that the ZIP file was missing the jQuery library files, among with other JS files.

These files were supposed to be included in the solution, but for reasons beyond our understanding, they were not.

To fix this, we had to manually remove the affected files, from the peoject (by copying them to a safe location and then deleting them on the project), recompile the project, and then add the files again (and recompile again).

With these steps VS was not including all the files in the ZIP. Finally.